# Can I use Firebase Dynamic Links to redirect out of my app and into another not owned by me?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a use case where I want to be able to press a button in my Flutter app and open my associate's installed app, or the Play Store page so my user can download my associate's app.

I have been investigating Firebase Dynamic Links to do that.

Using the Firebase dashboard `Define link behavior for Android` it only allows me to set up a deep link into an app that is in my Firebase project (and not my friend's app, which I don't own).

Am I misunderstanding how to set Firebase Dynamic Links up, or is it just not suitable for my use case?

Answer (score 1):

For you to create a dynamic link to your friend app, you will need access to your friend app. He/she can grant you limited access to his/her app using project invite. When the access is granted, you will be able to see his app during the dynamic link creation process.

If it is not possible to have access to this app, you can use another way to navigate a user to your friend app as follows

Use [flutter_appavailability](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability) package. This plugin allows you to check if an app is installed in mobile and using this plugin you can launch an app.

It will open the link in WebView using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) if not installed. But in this case you will programmatically check user platform and redirect to the appropriate link using your friend's app links

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that Firebase may not be the way to go. I assumed it would make things easier but clearly not (an additional API call and a load of hoops to jump through). I'll test out the appavailability package and report back how I got on. Cheers